# I want to color text with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, matrix

Ok, so I want to remake the matrix rain using Javascript, and it went well (this is my first "program"), but i want to change the first character in the "rain" to start off as white and transition to green then fades off to black.
Now I did the last two parts correctly, i just can't manage to make the first part. (which is the white text).

I need the leading** character to be white. so the character that's leading the "rain" to be constantly white( I'm not sure if its possible). for example: the if(drops[i] == 1), the 1 is the first line on the screen, and that's where I need the value to change so that if the character that lights up is the at the very bottom of the rain it becomes white and then when the next one lights up it changes to green while the one after changes to white (from top to bottom).

This is the intended result:
[Wanted Result](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Digital_rain_animation_medium_letters_shine.gif)

here's the complete code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//making the canvas full screen
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

var chinese = "ﾊﾐﾋｰｳｼﾅﾓﾆｻﾜﾂｵﾘｱﾎﾃﾏｹﾒｴｶｷﾑﾕﾗｾﾈｽﾀﾇﾍｦｲｸｺｿﾁﾄﾉﾌﾔﾖﾙﾚﾛﾝ012345789:・.\"=*+-<>";
//converting the string into an array of single characters
chinese = chinese.split("");

var font_size = 12;
var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
  drops[x] = 1;
//drawing the characters

function draw() {
  //Black BG for the canvas
  //translucent BG to show trail
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // Create gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0" //green text
  ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
  //looping over drops
  for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
    //a random chinese character to print
    var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random() * chinese.length)];
    //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
    ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

    //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
    //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis

    if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
      drops[i] = 0;

    //incrementing Y coordinate
    drops[i]++;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 95);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: black
}

canvas {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

The code written is with a lot of help so I might not understand certain stuff (I think I get it for the most part).

Comment: If you just want text to be white, makthe color white here:  ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0" //green text

Comment: I need the **first** character to be white and what follows to be green on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go mate, just adjusted the JS for this. I just had it save the generated text so that it draws the new generated text in white then redraws the previous text in green on the space above it, and then finally replaces the previous text with the new text.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//making the canvas full screen
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

var chinese = "ﾊﾐﾋｰｳｼﾅﾓﾆｻﾜﾂｵﾘｱﾎﾃﾏｹﾒｴｶｷﾑﾕﾗｾﾈｽﾀﾇﾍｦｲｸｺｿﾁﾄﾉﾌﾔﾖﾙﾚﾛﾝ012345789:・.\"=*+-<>";
//converting the string into an array of single characters
chinese = chinese.split("");

var font_size = 12;
var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
  drops[x] = 1;

//Hold text for next redraw
var previousText = [];
 
//drawing the characters
function draw() {
  //Black BG for the canvas
  //translucent BG to show trail
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
  
  //looping over drops
  for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {

    //a random chinese character to print
    var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random() * chinese.length)];

    //Draw in white
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
    ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

    //Draw in green
    ctx.fillStyle ="#0F0";
    ctx.fillText(previousText[i], i * font_size, (drops[i] - 1) * font_size);
    previousText[i] = text;


    //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
    //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis

    if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
      drops[i] = 0;

    //incrementing Y coordinate
    drops[i]++;
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 95);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: black
}

canvas {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```